# get the value of item view clicked with android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in android which has the following xml:

```
 <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_assurance" />
```

and the listItem in other xml file

I want to get the value of the item clicked in a listView.
I worked with the baseAdapter 
this is my code:

```
public class InscriptionAssuranceRemorqueur extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

public static ArrayList<Assurance> assuranceArray = new ArrayList<Assurance>();
private ListView list_assurance;
private Button btn_confirmation;
private CheckBox checkbox;

private double largeur;
private double longueur;
private double poids;
private String nom;
private String mail;
private String tel;
private String mdp;
private TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fen_inscription_assurance_remorqueur);

    //Intent
    Intent x = this.getIntent();
    nom = x.getExtras().getString("nomCompagnie");
    mail = x.getExtras().getString("mail");
    tel = x.getExtras().getString("tel");
    mdp = x.getExtras().getString("mdp");
    String largeur = x.getExtras().getString("largeur");
    String longueur = x.getExtras().getString("longueur");
    String poids  = x.getExtras().getString("poids");
    this.largeur = Double.parseDouble(largeur);
    this.longueur = Double.parseDouble(longueur);
    this.poids = Double.parseDouble(poids);


    //remplir le tab des compagnies d'assurance
    assuranceArray.add(new Assurance("Gat@gmail.com","GAT"));
    assuranceArray.add(new Assurance("STAR@gmail.com","STAR"));
    assuranceArray.add(new Assurance("Comar@gmail.com","Comar"));
    assuranceArray.add(new Assurance("Ctama@gmail.com","Ctama"));

    //Récupération

    list_assurance = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_assurance);
    btn_confirmation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_cfrm_as_rm);

    //Adapter
    MonAdapter adapter = new MonAdapter(this,assuranceArray);
    list_assurance.setAdapter(adapter);
    list_assurance.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    //Ecouteurs

    btn_confirmation.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_assurance,null);
    txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_assurance);
    checkbox = (CheckBox) layout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_assurance);
    if(v==checkbox)
    {


        Log.d("test",txt.getText().toString());

    }
}}
```

my item view xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/gris"
        android:id="@+id/txt_assurance"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_assurance"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

my Adapter :

```
public class MonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Assurance> assuranceArray;
private Context c;
private TextView txt;
public MonAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Assurance> list) {
    this.assuranceArray = list;
    this.c=c;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return assuranceArray.size();
}

@Override
public Assurance getItem(int position) {
    return assuranceArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return assuranceArray.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(c);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_assurance,null);
    txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_assurance);
    txt.setText((CharSequence)getItem(position).getNomCompagnie());


    return layout;
}}
```

So I have that listView which contains a textView and a checkbox, what I need is to get the text of the item checked ! please hellp

Comment: Your words "to get the text of the item checked" is not enough to understand what you want. Clearly explain in more words what do you exactly want and when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutally, `position` variable inside of `onItemClick` method should correspond to the position of the item clicked of the listView. If you want to take the value of the `assuranceArray` that is stored in clicked listview item then you need to use that `position` variable. For instance, your solution can look like:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String email = assuranceArray.get(position).getEmail()
}
```

Here, `getEmail()` method is just my guess. You need to replace it with your own method specified inside of `Assurance` model class.

**EDIT:**

If you want to add a `CheckBox` to your listView items and then want to know if it is checked or not you can use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String email = assuranceArray.get(position).getEmail();
    boolean isChecked = ( (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_assurance)).isChecked();
}
```

However, you need to remember that whenever you are adding some `clickable` view element to listView item, it will make listItem **unclickable**. `Checkbox` is one of such views. To solve the problem you need to include following attribute to parent layout of `listItem.xml`:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: I want to add a check box in the item, how can i get the value checked?

Comment: @BenMustaphaSabrine I have updated my answer. Take a look at it and let me know if it solved your problem. Consider upvoting my answer, I will appreciate it

Comment: that doesn't work, about the listView I w used the baseAdapter.Should I use threads?

Comment: @BenMustaphaSabrine I have a project with the ListView and BaseAdapter. This method works. Check one more time how you have implemented everything. I think you've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @BenMustaphaSabrine can you specify what do you mean doesn't work? What exactly doesn't work and what do you want to get?

Comment: when I check my checkbox no thing happens

Comment: So you mean that it doesn't get a tick inside of a box? If yes, then you need to update your question with the codes of your listItem.xml

Comment: I have that tick, but no I didn't get the one clicked

Comment: Can you explain in more details your problem and the functionality you want to achieve? It is really hard to understand you

Comment: okey I will add my code source to my question, what I want to do : get item checked